# How do you save certain items for specific users in mongodb?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I'm working on a job tracker app.

User creates an account, saving the user in a mongodb collection.

```
const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  date: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
  }
});
```

```
const JobSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  position: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  company: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  status: {
    type: String,
    default: "applied"
  },
  date: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
  }
});
```

When a user adds a job, how would you store (.post) and retrieve (.get) that data to correspond to that specific user only?

Is there a way to save the users "_id" to the jobs added, and searchById to get the jobs?

Answer (score 1):

It depends what exactly you want to achieve meaning what type of relationships your models will have. Lets say your users will have multiple jobs the best approach would be to store an array of `ObjectId`s. The `ref`option tells mongoose which collections to search during population of the array

```
const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
     name: {
     type: String,
     required: true
    },
    email: {
     type: String,
     required: true
    },
    password: {
     type: String,
     required: true
    },
    date: {
     type: Date,
     default: Date.now
    },
    jobs: [{type:Schema.Types.ObjecId,ref: 'Job'}]
 });
```

and then when you query the database you chain `populate('jobs')` after the query.
You can read more on the subject [here](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html)

Comment: Hmm, i may be doing something wrong, but when I add a job, the array from Users is still empty..

Comment: When you add a job you need to push that id to user jobs array in user collection.
When job is created for a user take that job id search for user with that user id and push/update (whichever you prefer) job id in user collection.
Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

For example,

```
const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    date: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    }
});

const User = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);

async function updateUser() {
    let user = await User.findOne({"name": "a-unique-user-name-in-the-db"})

    let userId = user._id

    let newEmail = "asdf@asdf.com"

    let updated = await User.updateOne(
        { "_id": userId },
        {
            $set: {
                "email": newEmail,
            }
        }
    )

    if (updated) {
        console.log("updated")
    }
}

updateUser();
```